# listing files using dotnetzip

Tags: c#, dotnetzip

```
using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(ExistingZipFile))  
  {  
    foreach (ZipEntry e in zip)  
    {  
      if (header)  
      {  
        System.Console.WriteLine("Zipfile: {0}", zip.Name);  
        if ((zip.Comment != null) && (zip.Comment != ""))   
          System.Console.WriteLine("Comment: {0}", zip.Comment);  
        System.Console.WriteLine("\n{1,-22} {2,8}  {3,5}   {4,8}  {5,3} {0}",  
                                 "Filename", "Modified", "Size", "Ratio", "Packed", "pw?");  
        System.Console.WriteLine(new System.String('-', 72));  
        header = false;  
      }  
      System.Console.WriteLine("{1,-22} {2,8} {3,5:F0}%   {4,8}  {5,3} {0}",  
                               e.FileName,  
                               e.LastModified.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),  
                               e.UncompressedSize,  
                               e.CompressionRatio,  
                               e.CompressedSize,  
                               (e.UsesEncryption) ? "Y" : "N");  

    }  
  }
```

I am using above code to print list of flies inside zip file.can somebody tell me what is header over here.(I a  writing this in asp.net code behind using c# as language,but this showing as error).Please help.

Comment: header is a boolean value. What is your error?

Comment: it's not able to recognize header(it underlines with red saying "The name 'header' does not exist in current context).

Comment: i actually the code from   http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CS-Examples&referringTitle=Examples

Comment: Where is *header* defined? Surely you looked for it before posting the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading your comment i would say you need to declare and initialize the header variable. Something like this:

```
using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(ExistingZipFile))  
  {  
    bool header = true;
    foreach (ZipEntry e in zip)  
    {  
      if (header)  
...
```